# is it safe to call a sharedInstance inside of a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I am calling a sharedInstance Class method inside a for loop, I understand the basics behind a shareInstace effectively working as a singleton however I am unsure of the implications of using one inside a for loop.

This is what my code looks like

```
- (IBAction)callItem:(id)sender {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < [_items count]; i++) {
        SingleItem *sItem = [_items objectAtIndex:i];
        [[SyncMod sharedInstance] downloadData: sItem._id];
    }
}
```

So in the above code snippet I am trying to download Data of multiple items, using a singleton class called SyncMod.

Will this work? what should I be careful of? pros and cons?

Comment: It will work (although you haven't shown the implementation of your singleton, so it is possible that it won't) but why wouldn't you just grab the singleton reference into a local variable before the loop?

Comment: Well i haven't declared before because I am not sure how to do that. I also thought that each iteration of the loop would require a new singleton?

Comment: By definition there is only one instance of a singleton; that is why you use a singleton pattern.

Comment: I understand that but my confusion stems from the for loop, dose the for loop continue after the shared instance has finished? then continue the for loop?

Comment: You would need to look at that code, but most likely `downloadData` completes asynchronously; so your `for` loop will quickly dispatch a number of download operations that will complete when the network is able to deliver the data.  I think the question you are trying to ask is "is `downloadData` thread safe?" - which you can only answer by inspecting that code

Comment: This looks like it is probably tied to a button, right? Presuming you have made `downloadData` behave synchronously, this would be a bad design as it will potentially hold up the main thread. You're better off making `downloadData` behave asynchronously. Aside from that, the normal flow in the loop is fine. `downloadData` will return and the next iteration of the loop will continue, provided `i < [_items count]`